# LinkedIn picture post not showing in preview

Tags: xml, rest, linkedin-api, mime, preview

I'm posting through the XML REST API to the LinkedIn. The thing XML I send out looks like this:

```
<share>
  <visibility>
    <code>anyone</code>
  </visibility>
  <comment>butah</comment>
  <content>
    <submitted-url>http://fully-qualified-url-to/bitly</submitted-url>
    <submitted-image-url>https://fully-qualified-url-to/image.png</submitted-image-url>
  </content>
</share>
```

The post shows up, the link works, and all the other fields (also if I add description and title, they work) show up properly, but the picture preview does not - instead it's an empty image.

I have tried some approaches:

1. The mime type (image/png) appears to be correct judging from curl result
2. I have tried with different TLS and SSL versions
3. I have tried multiple different images

I am at a loss - what else could be wrong? Copy-pasting the FQ image URL to a browser works splendidly as well. Any ideas?

[edit] Should be noted that I'm using the Company API.

**Update** This is most certainly a server configuration issue as I found some domains this works perfectly for. At least curl suggested the correct mime type is being returned. What else could cause the LinkedIn image caching to fail?

Comment: Did you check the resulting HTML to see where it thinks the image is residing?

Comment: The HTML on the linkedin page links to:
https://media.licdn.com/media-proxy/ext?w=180&h=110&f=c&hash=TX%2BxBCjLend2RwPzipP8mtImLPo%3D&ora=1%2CaFBCTXdkRmpGL2lvQUFBPQ%2CxAVta5g-0R65hxodyxImrqOEqFuj60ROC4HTDy_kG3n1q4HDfyO4PZbAea34-QxBLXBYwhsyYK32FC20Rsr4ft7xPYIm

Opening it shows an 1x1 white pixel image.

Comment: Can you add title & description and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Tried. The title and description display correctly, but picture is still broken.

Comment: Your XML is correct, you tried different images, so that also sounds correct. To state the obvious: You are stuck pretty good. Tried contacting LinkedIn yet?

Comment: I haven't contacted LinkedIn yet, no. And yep, I'm stuck. I'm guessssing this could be some form of server configuration issue, but can't wrap my mind around what the problem actually could be.

Comment: Could it be the difference between HTTPS and HTTP for serving the image?

Comment: The picture is only available through HTTPS, but I do believe it probably has something to do with certificates.

Comment: You could host the picture yourself elsewhere temporarily to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously LinkedIn is trying to pull the image into its CDN (Akamai), and most likely is failing in the attempt.

I would have to guess that whatever client LinkedIn is using to retrieve the image, it is failing. This could be because the SSL certificate fails the client's validation checks, it could be because the server is not receiving the proper request headers (`accept`, `accept-encoding`, `user-agent`, even `cookie` if it is trying to prevent bots or has access controls) for the server to serve the image, or it could be because the image is in a format the client doesn't support (I'm thinking `WebP`).

Also, you might be confused by caching or de-duping on LinkedIn's side. If, for example, you send them an image one time and it fails to load properly but does not generate an error condition, it is possible that LinkedIn considers that image loaded into its CMS/CDN and will not try to load it again when you try adding it again. Less likely is a failure to negotiate an acceptable SSL/TLS level and cipher suite, as just about everyone supports backward compatibility over security (which is a whole other issue).

Do you have access to the image server logs? My next step in trying to understand the situation would be to monitor the request from LinkedIn to the image server and see how that is going.